# Draw canvas on Google Maps v2

Tags: android, canvas, google-maps-api-2, ondraw

How I can draw a canvas on google maps fragment in Android application with Google Api V2 ?
I would draw a rectangle on Google Map but no with markers.
thanks.

Comment: you cannot use any `Canvas` API, sorry

Comment: ok thanks, and how I can draw on google maps? @pskink

Comment: thanks a lot @pskink..you know the way to draw (with markers) a rectangle resizable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a marker with a custom image:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.blue_point))
.snippet("Your " + "location is here"));
```

For more information see how to change the map marker icon at this link: http://kb4dev.com/article/android-google-map-integration-with-location-api